# What is the Le Magritte in the hats in Winter bash?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2012

How to win the [le-magritte](http://winterba.sh/le-magritte) hat in Winter Bash ?

Comment: You have to review 5 things in the review panel... Click the "review" link in the top bar. What's confusing about it?

Comment: @animuson He can't click it. He has 101 rep.

Comment: @AustinHenley: He has 800 on SO. You only need 125 for the lowest task.

Comment: @animuson My mistake. Was looking at his SU.

Comment: I need 125 reps in StackOverflow  to get the review link ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've rights to review ....so reviewing 5 items, you'll be getting [le-magritte](http://winterba.sh/le-magritte) hat

[image: Review]

The minimum reputation needed to do anything is that required for [down-voting](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down). At this level, you can review First Posts and Late Answers.

For more info you can have a read [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148504/at-what-reputation-can-i-start-reviewing)

Answer (score 1):

By reviewing 5 posts. Click the "Review" button at the top.